# How do I turn this form into a search form?

Tags: search, navigation

Hi I have an expanding search form inside the wordpress header and would like to make it work with my theme?

https://jsfiddle.net/u08cutgf/

```
<div class="search">
search
<input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: Where is your search form. This also seems to be not related to Wordpress at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this ,

```
<form name="searchBox" action="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>" class="search-form" method="get" role="search" >
        <input type="text" name="s" class="searchBox" placeholder="search" value="<?= $_GET['s'] ?>" required />
         <button type="submit" class="searchBtn" >search</button>
                  </form>
```